# Pattern matching :: case class

Tags: scala

Looking at the source code for immutable.List, I see this

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B,
                       private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
    override def tail : List[B] = tl
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

My understanding of case classes is that this signature is invalid because:

- constructor parameters are not all public
- constructor parameters are not all vals

Can somebody explain to me how this is working?

Comment: Quite simple: Both of your assumptions are wrong. Constructor parameters don't have to be public, and they can also be `var`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not forbidden that constructor parameters are non-public. The extractor will still work. The reason it was made package-private is exactly because it is a variable, and so the user cannot alter the value (but only read it through the `tail` method). Again this is not forbidden, but just generally strongly discouraged. You should not normally use a `var` because the case-class' equality and hash-code depend on the constructor arguments.

List uses a `var` here simply to make it easier to assemble new lists. If you look at the source code, you can see this for example in the [`take` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L205). And you can also see that `tl` is assigned only internally during the construction of new lists. Once they are returned, that variable is not touched any longer, and therefore equality is not broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are missing "by default".
*By default* constructor parameters are vals and public. 
I.e., if you say `case class Foo(bar: String)`, that'll make `bar` a `val` and public. Doesn't mean, you can't still say `case class Foo(private var bar: String)`